# Using Virtualenv to install two versions of a program

Tags: python, virtualenv

so I have a question about installing multiple versions of a single program. Apparently I need to use Weblogo-3.3 for one part of my project, but another program I'm using for a different part uses Weblogo-2.8.2 as a dependency, and cannot work with 3.3. This is...problematic, as I need to do both parts. Both use python 2.7.

Is there any way I can use a virtual environment to selectively install and run Weblogo-2.8? I'm concerned that even if I do that and try to run the program that uses it as a dependency, it will try and call the Weblogo-3.3. Won't they both be in python's dist-packages folder and cause conflicts?

I was about to try to install it with Virtualenv, but I didn't want to mess up my current installation of Weblogo-3.3 so I was going to hold off until I knew for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what virtual environments are for.

Create your virtual environment and activate, then any 'pip install' or 'easy_install' that you do will only affect that environment, not your site.

If I were you once you get 2.8 working, install 3.0 in a different virtenv and then think about deleting the site-wide Weblogo.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Okay, yeah I didn't want to do anything that would require me having to reinstall everything to fix. I probably will do that (use 3.3 in a virtual env.), I just really wish I had known about virtual environments before ....like yesterday. Would have saved me a lot of time over the past couple of months. Alas. Thanks for the help!